# how to ignore physics collision of some objects in box2d

Tags: physics, box2d

I know this sounds silly but I would like some objects to follow physics while others not to collide each other.

I tried to achieve them by setting their position exclusively. But then it will ignore all physics.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but kinematic bodies might help as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read up on collision filtering in the Box2D manual:

> Collision filtering allows you to prevent collision between fixtures.
>   For example, say you make a character that rides a bicycle. You want
>   the bicycle to collide with the terrain and the character to collide
>   with the terrain, but you don't want the character to collide with the
>   bicycle (because they must overlap). Box2D supports such collision
>   filtering using categories and groups.
>
> Box2D supports 16 collision categories. For each fixture you can
>   specify which category it belongs to. You also specify what other
>   categories this fixture can collide with. For example, you could
>   specify in a multiplayer game that all players don't collide with each
>   other and monsters don't collide with each other, but players and
>   monsters should collide

Link to manual [here](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf).  (Search for Filtering)
.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two kinds of objects that should not collide with another, then the following works.

```
var kindA = -1;
var kindB = -2;

var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
var body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
var fixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = new b2Shape();
fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex =
    entity instanceof EntityA
        ? kindA
        : kindB;
body.CreateFixture(fixture);
```