# Box2d - Allow object to pass but still report collision

Tags: collision-detection, box2d

I am creating a laser which is a dynamic body with its own collision filtering. I want it to not collide, as it does not currently but I want it to still report the collision or when the two overlap. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Report the collision in the collision filtering. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22540/how-to-ignore-physics-collision-of-some-objects-in-box2d?rq=1

Comment: @Byte56 Can you elaborate? If I filter the collision so they can pass won't that not report the collision?

Comment: If you're filtering the collision, you know they've come in contact right? You make sure they don't respond to the collision and you report the collision to whatever you're reporting collisions to. Do you mean something else by "report collision"?

Comment: @Byte56 I'm not filtering it myself - it's all handled by the physics engine and it just ignores them.

Comment: I see, check out this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57818/using-box2d-for-range-detection/57820#57820 if you want to implement that stuff yourself. The solvers are where you'll want to report and decide not to do collision response.

Comment: "it's all handled by the physics engine and it just ignores them" - You mean you are not able to listen for collisions? Which engine/language are you using? In Box2D the default is no filtering - everything collides with everything.

Comment: ? Could you show some code perhaps, it's not clear what is the bug otherwise

Comment: @Byte56 All of the answers you gave were unhelpful. The solution was much more simple. Can you unlock this so I can actually provide an answer?